Is bicycle decathlon st100 suitable for long rides?
I have a MTB Cycle. I wish to take this cycle for long distance as it was suggested to not go for longer rides. I am not sure to look for a good bike with reasonable option in India. If anyone could suggest a good option or doing adjustment to ST100 for long distance ride suggestions are welcome. I would be grateful for you

Welcome to the site. Please take the  https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/tour and consider a look into our https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help pages.

Concerning your question: can you elaborate what "long distance" is for you, which type of terrain (flat, hilly etc) and what road surfaces you have in mind. Depending on those factors, it  may vary a lot whether your bike might be suitable or not.

Hi, welcome to bicycles.  I'm afraid recommendation questions aren't a good fit for the site; there are probably better sites around for product recommendations.

If it's what you've got, and you're capable of the ride, then it's possible. I've done 200km day rides on a basic (but a bit more expensive than that) hardtail, but I was confident in myself and my saddle. So you really need to think in terms of what's "long" for you

The bike you have is infinitely more suitable than the bike you covert.
